# jQuery file upload: cannot upload file in Safari 11

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Steps to reproduce the bug in Safari 11:

1. Create a folder with Cyrillic letters in the title, for example "русский_язык"
2. Add some files to the folder
3. Open https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ in Safari 11.1 browser
4. Upload file from that folder

**Actual result**: file was not uploaded.

For a better understanding, watch the video for Safari 11: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16tU8iBn0U9bUs7u5pM4ZBXmxpfJIv8WV

Try to upload the same file but use Safari 10.

**Actual result**: all is good, file was uploaded without any problems.

For a better understanding, watch the video for Safari 10: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IO--Y1RjETAYAucaNyqhM6HZcQdNKDkI

**Update 28.05.2018**
After a few hours of debagging via crossbrowsertesting.com (because I do not have safari) I found temporary solution:
on this line https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L1182 need to replace

```
entries = fileInput.prop('webkitEntries') ||  fileInput.prop('entries')
```

to

```
entries = []
```

And everything should works.

I guess it happened becasuse apple added to safari experimental feature - FileSystemEntry. More info about this feature https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemEntry.

If `entries` variable will be empty jquery.fileupload.js will use
well-tried `files` attribute for getting uploaded files. Look to code https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L1189 for more details

Also I report a bug to Safari and to  Sebastian Tschan (author of this library)

Comment: I don't think report a bug here helps

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, maybe. but "Issue" section is closed in repo https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Solution u've adviced here is not working for me :(
Is there any news about fixing this issue?

Comment: @Dmitry, it should works. What exactly you do and what not working?

Comment: @VladimirKalyuzhny Hello, i've done this http://joxi.ru/RmzqpEYC0qpGqr , but still can't upload file in Safari 11 from Russian-letters folder

Comment: @VladimirKalyuzhny I've rechecked site and clear the cache and looks like your solution now works. Thanks! : )

Comment: @Dmitry, I`am glad to hear it

Comment: PR opened - https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/pull/3512 - let's solve it together.

Answer (score 7):

I found the same problem now. 
I have already detected that the code snippet:
jquery.fileupload.js

```
_handleFileTreeEntry: function (entry, path) {
        var that = this,
            dfd = $.Deferred(),
            errorHandler = function (e) {
                if (e && !e.entry) {
                    e.entry = entry;
                }
                // Since $.when returns immediately if one
                // Deferred is rejected, we use resolve instead.
                // This allows valid files and invalid items
                // to be returned together in one set:
                dfd.resolve([e]);
            },
            successHandler = function (entries) {
                that._handleFileTreeEntries(
                    entries,
                    path + entry.name + '/'
                ).done(function (files) {
                    dfd.resolve(files);
                }).fail(errorHandler);
            },
            readEntries = function () {
                dirReader.readEntries(function (results) {
                    if (!results.length) {
                        successHandler(entries);
                    } else {
                        entries = entries.concat(results);
                        readEntries();
                    }
                }, errorHandler);
            },
            dirReader, entries = [];
        path = path || '';
        if (entry.isFile) {
            if (entry._file) {
                // Workaround for Chrome bug #149735
                entry._file.relativePath = path;
                dfd.resolve(entry._file);
            } else {
                entry.file(function (file) {  // <=== here
                    file.relativePath = path;
                    dfd.resolve(file);
                }, errorHandler);
            }
        } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
            dirReader = entry.createReader();
            readEntries();
        } else {
            // Return an empy list for file system items
            // other than files or directories:
            dfd.resolve([]);
        }
        return dfd.promise();
```

}

in this function, when the code run into the condition

```
            entry.file(function (file) {
                file.relativePath = path;
                dfd.resolve(file);
            }, errorHandler);
```

Safari is return the errorHandler for the file function callback. the function api reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry/file.

It must be Safari 11's bug. After soon I will report the bug for Apple.
In jQuery.fileupload.js， I guess the better fixed method is detect the UserAgent with Safari 11. But I think Apple should fix this problem.

Comment: The funny thing is that the same behavior but the target is the desktop folder, it totally works. it sucks me!

Comment: Stevenhong, I've updated my post. Added my temprorary solution how to fix this bug

Comment: I report the bug to Apple with https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=39969255

Comment: It seems that Safari Preview version has new release to download. Maybe you can try. but the OS need MacOS High Sierra.  You see: https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced same bug with a folder name contains Japanese characters, and caught `NotFoundError: Path does not exist` [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/a451d60bb8034e2736082e24cf7aa7f9dbed5b8a/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L1089) same as [@Stevenhong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50059309/9924356) (macOS 10.13.4 and Safari 11.1).

I succeeded in uploading same files when I use Safari Technology Preview Release 58!